# how to get property value in umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Hi guys I'm new here also in **Umbraco cms**. I created a document types and it has a property`(media picker)`.
My questions is how can i call the`media picker`into different page.
Let say i will create another page and will call the property that i created from the other page.
Hope someone can help me. 
I've search through their website and google but i have no luck to find a better solution.

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("teaserImage"))
{
    var caseStudyImagesList = CurrentPage.CaseStudyImages.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var caseStudyImagesCollection = Umbraco.Media(caseStudyImagesList);

    foreach (var caseStudyImage in caseStudyImagesCollection)
    {
        <img src="@caseStudyImage.Url"  />
    }
}
```

Comment: So on a page A you have the property "teaserImage" and  you want to access it from page B?

Comment: yes that is correct..

Answer (score 2):

You can get the node of the page A from the page B in many ways.
For example:

```
// you can get the A node with its ID if you have it
int idPageA = 1207;
IPublishedContent nodeA = Umbraco.TypedContent(idPageA);
// or maybe by moving through the tree, Model.Content is the typed version of currentpage, so you have intellisense
IPublishedContent nodeA = Model.Content.Parent.Children().Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("propertyAlias") == "nodeA");
IPublishedContent nodeA = Model.Content.Parent.Children().Where(x => x.Name == "Node A Name");

if (nodeA.HasValue("teaserImage"))
{
    var caseStudyImagesList = nodeA.GetPropertyValue<string>(CaseStudyImages).Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var caseStudyImagesCollection = Umbraco.TypedMedia(caseStudyImagesList);

    foreach (var caseStudyImage in caseStudyImagesCollection)
    {
        if(caseStudyImage != null){
            <img src="@caseStudyImage.Url"  />
        }
    }
}
```